# Strange closure behaviour with print

Tags: r, closures

In the following R code, if I comment out the `print(i)` line, the result is

```
3
3
3
```

But with the `print`, the result is

```
1
2
3
```

I can't figure out why? How the print affects the result? Thanks!

```r
f <- vector('list',3)
# set the i'th function to return i
for(i in 1:length(f)) {
  f[[i]] <- (function(i){
    # STRANGE HERE!
    print(i)
    function(){i}
  })(i)
}
# apply the functions using a different loop variable
for(j in 1:length(f)) {
  print(f[[j]]())
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by strange? What may seem strange to you might be normal to another user.

Comment: I mean the last line `print(f[[j]]())` prints differently with/without the `print(i)` line. With it, I get `1 2 3`, without it, I get `3 3 3`

Comment: Maybe it's because the lazy evaluation.